# Tomcat crashes without error

Tags: java, tomcat, crash, raspberry-pi

I developed a very simple webapp and am aiming for deploying it on my raspberry pi where I got archlinux running. Once I run the startup script from tomcat the serverlogs end with

```
"INFO: Server startup in 322789 ms"
```

which is already quite long but I consider this might be due to the low performance offered by the raspberry. Anyway, during the startup phase and after the server started the command

```
"sudo lsof -n -P -i :8080"
```

runs successfully i.e. it shows me that a process is running listening on port 8080. However after issuing a simple wget on the server the same command shows no process anymore indicating that tomcat crashed. Further there are no errors in any logs of tomcat. Actually the "localhost_access_log.xxxxx" has the content:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2014:17:02:06 -0600] "GET /volleyball-tool-backend/index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 1068
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2014:17:02:06 -0600] "GET /volleyball-tool-backend/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1068
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2014:18:26:34 -0600] "GET /volleyball-tool-backend/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1068
```

Indicating that the requests were served successfully.

EDIT:

I double checked and indeed the server does successfully process at least one initial request. Afterwards it crashes.

Output of the catalina.out log (one startup cycle):

```
Mar 11, 2014 7:36:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 11, 2014 7:36:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52
Mar 11, 2014 7:36:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /home/ben/servers/volleyball-tool/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/volleyball-tool-backend.war
Mar 11, 2014 7:39:08 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [355] milliseconds.
Mar 11, 2014 7:39:22 PM org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler initialize
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version Jersey: 2.6 2014-02-18 21:52:53...
Mar 11, 2014 7:39:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/ben/servers/volleyball-tool/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/manager
Mar 11, 2014 7:39:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/ben/servers/volleyball-tool/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/host-manager
Mar 11, 2014 7:40:19 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/ben/servers/volleyball-tool/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/examples
Mar 11, 2014 7:41:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/ben/servers/volleyball-tool/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/ROOT
Mar 11, 2014 7:41:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /home/ben/servers/volleyball-tool/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/docs
Mar 11, 2014 7:41:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 11, 2014 7:41:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 11, 2014 7:41:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 311351 ms
```

By the way: For deploying my war file I just dropped it into the webapps folder of tomcat before starting it.

EDIT:

Content of "localhost.xxxxx" log:

```
Mar 11, 2014 5:01:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Mar 11, 2014 5:01:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Mar 11, 2014 5:01:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@1f718f2')
Mar 11, 2014 6:25:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Mar 11, 2014 6:25:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Mar 11, 2014 6:25:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@19df57a')
Mar 11, 2014 6:38:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Mar 11, 2014 6:38:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Mar 11, 2014 6:38:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@1dfdee0')
Mar 11, 2014 6:55:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Mar 11, 2014 6:55:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Mar 11, 2014 6:55:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@162108e')
Mar 11, 2014 7:41:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Mar 11, 2014 7:41:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Mar 11, 2014 7:41:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@162108e')
```

EDIT:

I checked `dmesg`:

```
[12259.897659] CPU: 0 PID: 12282 Comm: java Not tainted 3.10.33-1-ARCH #1
[12259.897731] [<c0013428>] (unwind_backtrace+0x0/0xec) from [<c00112d0>] (show_stack+0x10/0x14)
[12259.897776] [<c00112d0>] (show_stack+0x10/0x14) from [<c05a1ad0>] (dump_header.isra.15+0x84/0x1c4)
[12259.897815] [<c05a1ad0>] (dump_header.isra.15+0x84/0x1c4) from [<c00b6558>] (oom_kill_process+0x278/0x3f8)
[12259.897845] [<c00b6558>] (oom_kill_process+0x278/0x3f8) from [<c00b6b6c>] (out_of_memory+0x280/0x2cc)
[12259.897877] [<c00b6b6c>] (out_of_memory+0x280/0x2cc) from [<c00babbc>] (__alloc_pages_nodemask+0x880/0x968)
[12259.897906] [<c00babbc>] (__alloc_pages_nodemask+0x880/0x968) from [<c00d2e90>] (__pte_alloc+0x20/0x180)
[12259.897936] [<c00d2e90>] (__pte_alloc+0x20/0x180) from [<c00d6000>] (handle_mm_fault+0xd8/0xf0)
[12259.897970] [<c00d6000>] (handle_mm_fault+0xd8/0xf0) from [<c05aab14>] (do_page_fault+0x26c/0x3e8)
[12259.897999] [<c05aab14>] (do_page_fault+0x26c/0x3e8) from [<c0008354>] (do_DataAbort+0x34/0x98)
[12259.898026] [<c0008354>] (do_DataAbort+0x34/0x98) from [<c05a94fc>] (__dabt_usr+0x3c/0x40)
[12259.898041] Exception stack(0xca323fb0 to 0xca323ff8)
[12259.898061] 3fa0:                                     a81fffe8 a24cd068 00000090 00000000
[12259.898082] 3fc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 a28aaf0c b05bb570 a28aaf00
[12259.898101] 3fe0: 00000000 a18a95e4 00000000 b6de9c00 20000010 ffffffff
[12259.898112] Mem-info:
[12259.898124] Normal per-cpu:
[12259.898136] CPU    0: hi:   42, btch:   7 usd:  26
[12259.898164] active_anon:29834 inactive_anon:43 isolated_anon:0
 active_file:176 inactive_file:2050 isolated_file:0
 unevictable:0 dirty:0 writeback:0 unstable:0
 free:82664 slab_reclaimable:653 slab_unreclaimable:972
 mapped:555 shmem:95 pagetables:243 bounce:0
 free_cma:74731
[12259.898231] Normal free:330656kB min:32768kB low:40960kB high:49152kB active_anon:119336kB inactive_anon:172kB active_file:704kB inactive_file:8200kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:487424kB managed:170128kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:2220kB shmem:380kB slab_reclaimable:2612kB slab_unreclaimable:3888kB kernel_stack:824kB pagetables:972kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB free_cma:298924kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:331 all_unreclaimable? yes
[12259.898248] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0
[12259.898266] Normal: 74*4kB (UEMC) 53*8kB (EC) 43*16kB (UEM) 21*32kB (UEC) 26*64kB (UEM) 16*128kB (EMC) 13*256kB (UEMC) 10*512kB (UEMC) 3*1024kB (UEC) 3*2048kB (UMC) 75*4096kB (MRC) = 330656kB
[12259.898353] 2321 total pagecache pages
[12259.898368] 0 pages in swap cache
[12259.898379] Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
[12259.898388] Free swap  = 0kB
[12259.898396] Total swap = 0kB
[12259.929094] 121856 pages of RAM
[12259.929126] 82868 free pages
[12259.929136] 3488 reserved pages
[12259.929145] 1275 slab pages
[12259.929154] 263343 pages shared
[12259.929163] 0 pages swap cached
[12259.929174] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes swapents oom_score_adj name
[12259.929219] [   69]     0    69     4980      140      12        0             0 systemd-journal
[12259.929240] [   83]     0    83     2372       80       6        0         -1000 systemd-udevd
[12259.929260] [  106]     0   106      418       12       5        0             0 rngd
[12259.929279] [  107]     0   107     1568       96       6        0         -1000 sshd
[12259.929298] [  108]     0   108      700      127       4        0             0 crond
[12259.929320] [  110]     0   110      520       22       5        0             0 avahi-dnsconfd
[12259.929340] [  111]     0   111      435       24       4        0             0 ifplugd
[12259.929359] [  114]     0   114      639       45       5        0             0 systemd-logind
[12259.929378] [  115]    84   115      794       53       5        0             0 avahi-daemon
[12259.929397] [  116]    81   116      929       99       5        0          -900 dbus-daemon
[12259.929416] [  117]     0   117     1202      767       6        0             0 haveged
[12259.929436] [  118]    84   118      758       35       5        0             0 avahi-daemon
[12259.929455] [  123]     0   123      445       20       5        0             0 agetty
[12259.929473] [  124]     0   124      445       19       5        0             0 agetty
[12259.929523] [  234]     0   234      512       37       5        0             0 dhcpcd
[12259.929545] [  365]    89   365   127778    12469      57        0             0 mysqld
[12259.929568] [11939]     0 11939     2572      167       8        0             0 sshd
[12259.929587] [11943]     0 11943      851       66       5        0             0 systemd
[12259.929607] [11944]     0 11944     1770      273       6        0             0 (sd-pam)
[12259.929626] [11945]     0 11945      811       65       5        0             0 bash
[12259.929644] [11946]     0 11946     1094       66       6        0             0 su
[12259.929663] [11947]  1000 11947      840       78       5        0             0 bash
[12259.929701] [12280]     0 12280    99612    15513      63        0             0 java
[12259.929717] Out of memory: Kill process 12280 (java) score 127 or sacrifice child
[12259.937632] Killed process 12280 (java) total-vm:398448kB, anon-rss:60236kB, file-rss:1816kB
```

Obviously it says out of memory. Note that I am also encountering this error when running the default tomcat setup without my webapp. What can I do about it?

I also made a COMPLETE reset of the raspberry and installed everyhing from scratch: The setup looks like this:

```
-RaspberryPi
-ArchlinuxARM
-OracleJVM/OpenJDK (both don't work)
-ApacheTomcat from: https://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi
-MariaDB
-Maria JDBC Connector from https://downloads.mariadb.org/client-java/
```

I further captured the output of atop here:

http://oi60.tinypic.com/dre936.jpg

Note the line which is indicated red concerning swap space. I don't have any clue what to infer from this though. As I said I made a complete new install using the "Noobs" tool from the Raspberry site so I assume they or the OS will take care of swaping.

Startupsequence: sudo ./[TOMCATDIR]/startup.sh

Regards

Comment: Did you check the catalina.out log? Any error there?

Comment: So Tomcat served the requests, so it didn't crash. So what's your question? Do you have a real problem, or is it just that `lsof` is confusing you?

Comment: It is a real problem indeed. The server does in fact stop running i.e. stop serving any content after an initial request. See edits above for more.

Comment: There should be another log file, localhost.yyyy-mm-dd.log, which records output from the JVM, including errors, as opposed to localhost_access_log.yyyy-mm-dd.log, which just records HTTP transactions. Can you check that?

Comment: I couldn't identify anything unusual in that log either. I attached its content at the bottom of my initial post.

Comment: Check the OS logs. It is possible that the OS killed the process because it was using too much memory. Other things you could do is enable GC logging and check that the memory being allocated is appropriate for your hardware.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I attached the dmesg log above.

Comment: I have no idea how to mark this thread as answered now, would be great if a SO guru takes care of it.

Comment: @user2820379: You could try lowering the max heap/permgen size to a more suitable value (via `$JAVA_OPTS`). The defaults are probably too high for Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a swap file did the trick. It really was a memory leackage thusly.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have deployed your app to webapp dir

Comment: There's no evidence here that he didn't, and if his webapp is deployed as `/volleyball-tool-backend` there is evidence here that he did. -1